# Cómo cambiar el color del fondo de un grid (divs) al hacer clic y arrastrar el cursor, y dejar de hacerlo al soltar el clic, en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo el projecto *etch-a-skecth* del curso de *The Odin Project*. Se trata de hacer un grid de 16x16 y cuando se le haga clic a uno de sus divs, este cambie de color.

Mi problema está en que, al hacer clic, se dispara el evento y empieza a cambiar el color del fondo, pero al soltar el clic, sigue cambiando el color si muevo el cursor sobre los divs.

Mi intención es que, al soltar el clic, deje de dibujar.

Estoy usando el evento de `mousedown` y `mouseover` respectivamente para lo dicho, e intenté hacerlo de varias maneras, pero no encuentro la forma de que me funcione. Lo último que traté es usar un `removeEventListener` y quitar el `mouseover`, pero no me sale.

También traté de usar el evento `mouseup` y dentro un `removeEventListener` al `mouseover`, pero tampoco me funcionó.

Dejo mi código para que se entienda mejor.

```js
const divCont = document.getElementById("grid-container");

for (i = 1; i<=16; i++) {
    let divCol = document.createElement('div')
    divCol.classList.add("grid");
    for ( j = 1; j<=16; j++){
        let divRow = document.createElement('div');
        divRow.classList.add("secGrid");
        divCol.appendChild(divRow);
    }
    divCont.appendChild(divCol);
}

const hoverDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.secGrid')];

function colorChange(){
    hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
        hoverDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
            hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black" 
            hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
                hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black"
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

/*function colorUnChange(){
    hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
        hoverDiv.addEventListener ('mouseup', () => {
            hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
                hoverDiv.removeEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black"
                })
            })
        })
    })
}*/

colorChange();

/*colorUnChange();*/
```

```css
* body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    max-width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
}

#grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    background-color: black;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.secGrid {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <script src="Etch-A-Sketch.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="grid-container"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta usar el evento onmouseup. También una variable para setear si está presionando o no (yo le llamé "Pintar"). Entonces si pintar es true minentras el mouseover se dispara, pinta el cuadro. Caso contrario no pinta

```js
const divCont = document.getElementById("grid-container");

for (i = 1; i<=16; i++) {
    let divCol = document.createElement('div')
    divCol.classList.add("grid");
    for ( j = 1; j<=16; j++){
        let divRow = document.createElement('div');
        divRow.classList.add("secGrid");
        divCol.appendChild(divRow);
    }
    divCont.appendChild(divCol);
}

const hoverDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.secGrid')];

let pintar=false;

hoverDivs.forEach(hoverDiv => {
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', () => 
 {
   pintar=true;
 });
 
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', () => 
 {
   pintar=false;
 });
 
 hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => 
 {
  if(pintar)
  {
    hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
});
});
```

```css
* body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    max-width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
}

#grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    background-color: black;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.secGrid {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <script src="Etch-A-Sketch.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="grid-container"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió a la perfección. Además de tu solución, a la primer parte le agregué al `onmousedown` el `hoverDiv.style.backgroundColor` así me aplicaba el el estilo al instante de hacer click, de la otra manera solo me aplicaba el estilo solo cuando pasaba al subsiguiente div.